# «Профессия – артистка». Можно ли поставить тире?

Tags: тире

«Профессия – артистка». Можно ли поставить тире?

Answer (score 1):

**Профессия – артистка**.

[Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_172)

> Существует несколько случаев, когда для интонационно-логического членения фразы между подлежащим и сказуемым необходимо поставить тире.
>
> 1. Если оба главных члена выражены существительными в именительном падеже, например:
>    Тамань – самый скверный городишко из всех приморских городов России (Лермонтов).

Пример из НКРЯ:

> Лет десять назад Мишель написал очень интересную книгу "Как открывать богов. **Профессия― импресарио**". Практически, он выучился этой профессии с нуля, поставил на ноги созданное им бюро. [Сати Спивакова. Не всё (2002)]

«[Профессия — киноактёр](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F_%E2%80%94_%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%91%D1%80)» — документальный фильм Станислава Ростоцкого.

Answer (score 0):

Если это предложение, то тире между подлежащим и сказуемым, выраженными сущ.  в форме И.п.,  ставится **в таком предложении** обязательно:

**Профессия – артистка.**

При отсутствии тире это будет **не предложение, а словосочетание** "приложение + определяемое существительное" (например, заголовок статьи).

Comment: Если словосочетание, то скорее *профессия артистки*: Ей-то, собственно, прятаться не приходилось: все понимали, что у нее ничего нет; но самая профессия артистки требовала, на сцене и в кулисах, постоянной подделки под роскошь. [М. А. Алданов. Чертов мост (1925)]

Comment: А в таком предложении: Профессия артист, прекрасный, но трудный выбор   http://www.proprof.ru/stati/careera/vybor-professii/o-professiyah/professiya-artist-prekrasnyy-no-trudnyy-vybor

Comment: Да, пожалуй, бывает и такое. Правда, источник не внушает доверия, но есть и в НКРЯ:  «Эта великая **профессия артист**». [Вера Иванова. Держать лицо и спину. Двенадцатый кинофестиваль «Созвездие»станет, скорее всего, последним (2001) // «Известия», 2001.08.05]

Comment: Однако название профессии в общем виде идет в м.р. В ж.р. такое представить трудно.